# Spark 2.0.0 truncate from Redshift table using jdbc

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, amazon-redshift, databricks

Hello I am using Spark SQL(2.0.0) with Redshift where I want to truncate my tables. I am using this [spark-redshift](https://github.com/databricks/spark-redshift) package & I want to know how I can truncate my table.Can anyone please share example of this ??

Answer (score 2):

I was unable to accomplish this using Spark and the code in the spark-redshift repo that you have listed above.

I was, however, able to use AWS Lambda with psycopg2 to truncate a redshift table.  Then I use boto3 to kick off my spark job via AWS Glue.

The important code below is cur.execute("truncate table yourschema.yourtable")

```
from __future__ import print_function
import sys
import psycopg2
import boto3

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    db_database = "your_redshift_db_name"
    db_user = "your_user_name"
    db_password = "your_password"
    db_port = "5439"
    db_host = "your_redshift.hostname.us-west-2.redshift.amazonaws.com"

    try:
        print("attempting to connect...")
        conn = psycopg2.connect(dbname=db_database, user=db_user, password=db_password, host=db_host, port=db_port)
        print("connected...")
        conn.autocommit = True
        cur = conn.cursor()
        count_sql = "select count(pivotid) from yourschema.yourtable"
        cur.execute(count_sql)
        results = cur.fetchone()

        print("countBefore: ", results[0])
        countOfPivots = results[0]
        if countOfPivots > 0:
            cur.execute("truncate table yourschema.yourtable")
            print("truncated yourschema.yourtable")
            cur.execute(count_sql)
            results = cur.fetchone()
            print("countAfter: ", results[0])

        cur.close()
        conn.close()

        glueClient = boto3.client("glue")
        startTriiggerResponse = glueClient.start_trigger(Name="your-awsglue-ondemand-trigger")
        print("startedTrigger:", startTriiggerResponse.Name)

        return results
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        raise e
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the `mode` to the library before calling save. For example:

```
my_dataframe.write
   .format("com.databricks.spark.redshift")
   .option("url", "jdbc:redshift://my_cluster.qwertyuiop.eu-west-1.redshift.amazonaws.com:5439/my_database?user=my_user&password=my_password")
   .option("dbtable", "my_table")
   .option("tempdir", "s3://my-bucket")
   .option("diststyle", "KEY")
   .option("distkey", "dist_key")
   .option("sortkeyspec", "COMPOUND SORTKEY(key_1, key_2)")
   .option("extracopyoptions", "TRUNCATECOLUMNS COMPUPDATE OFF STATUPDATE OFF")
   .mode("overwrite") // "append" / "error"
   .save()
```

Comment: what in the code provided allows the user to truncate any table?  is the implication that my_dataframe is an empty dataframe?

Comment: `.mode("overwrite")` will cause the existing data to be removed. The user specified in the Redshift URL must have the necessary permissions or it will error.

Comment: presumably my_dataframe is built on "my_table"?  if that assumption is correct, I think that .mode("overwrite") will write all of the data from my_table back into my table, and will not in-fact truncate anything.  what am I missing?