# PySpark save to Redshift table with "Overwirte" mode results in dropping table?

Tags: pyspark, aws-glue

Using PySpark in AWS Glue to load data from S3 files to Redshift table, in code used mode("Overwirte") got error stated that "can't drop table because other object depend on the table", turned out there is view created on top of that table, seams the "Overwrite" mode actually drop and re-create redshift table then load data, is there any option that only "truncate" table not dropping it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AWS Glue uses [databricks spark redshift connector](https://github.com/databricks/spark-redshift/blob/master/README.md) (it's not documented anywhere but I verified that empirically). Spark redshift connector's documentation mentions:

> Overwriting an existing table: By default, this library uses transactions to perform overwrites, which are implemented by deleting the destination table, creating a new empty table, and appending rows to it.

Answer (score 0):

Here there is a related discussion inline to your question, where they have used truncate instead of overwrite, also its a combination of lambda & glue.  Please refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40972861/spark-2-0-0-truncate-from-redshift-table-using-jdbc) for detailed discussions and code samples.  Hope this helps.

regards

Comment: that thread talked about using two jobs to truncate Redshift table first and run a AWS Glue job to load data. I'm trying to find a way to achieve this in one Glue job, i.e, plug in codes that connect to Redshift db and truncate target table then load data, is that possible? any sample code?